# Where would I start for reverse engineering a server connection, in order to build a server emulator?

Tags: reverse-engineering, server-side, packet-capture

I'm a long time game developer, and I've been considering writing a server emulator for a popular game. My assumptions so far are that when multiplayer is active, clients speak to each other and bypass a server, so all I would have to emulate would be matchmaking and initiating client connections to each other. The goal is not to circumvent any kind of security authentication, but to simply implement a better solution for a server system which is flaky as it stands. Also, the existing system has no level of cheat protection, so it won't be long before the online community is largely destroyed. If there are any legal questions about doing this, I will not release any of my work until such a time as the official servers are shut down.

Where would I start for this? I'm assuming I have to be able to log and track packets sent and received. What software would be good for that?

Any other tips or suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Thé authority whenever it comes to packet capture is [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) - formerly known as Ethereal. It will allow you to capture, filter and inspect packets, but you can extend wireshark and teach it to recognize new protocols - allowing you to inspect and understand the game package much more easily.

Wireshark can also open files containing packets captured by many other popular software, such as for example [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) on *NIX systems.

I'd advise you to download wireshark and quickly glance over the site, then run it and start capturing. Use a program which uses a (preferably simple) protocol you know and understand (IRC, FTP, HTTP, SMTP) and see what it does. Once you understand the basics about wireshark, fire up your desired application-to-reverse-engineer and get going!

Comment: I've never even coded any network stuff directly before so it should be an adventure. I'll try wireshark to get started with.

Answer (score 1):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is a tool that tracks packets being sent and received.